# change the color of one value in a continuous color key

Tags: r, ggplot2

This code

```
xy <-expand.grid(1:10,1:10)
xyz <- cbind(xy,0)
xyz[2:8,3] <- c(0.05,0.09,0.8,0.08,0.04,0.02,0.02)
colnames(xyz) <- c("x","y","z")
xyz <- as.data.frame(xyz)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(xyz,aes(x,y,fill=z))+geom_raster()
```

produces

[image: output of the code]

How can I change the color only for 0 (e.g., to yellowish)? I like to emphasize the difference between 0 and non-zero values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to turn 0 to NA and use `scale_fill_continuous` to color it.

```
library(ggplot2)

xyz$z[xyz$z == 0] <- NA

ggplot(xyz,aes(x,y,fill=z))+geom_raster() + 
  scale_fill_continuous(na.value = 'yellow')
```

[image]